# Callback inside a callback C#

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, callback

Trying to set up a server tool that subscribes to a service and notifies me when a event occurs via a callback. I have the subscription part working and when an event is triggered, it hits the callback, but i have this in a library and want to get it to the main project. I thought of doing it with a delegate, but can't think of the syntax.

*ClientSubscriber.cs*

```
/// <summary>
/// Used by Clients to subscribe to a particular queue
/// <param name="type">Subscription type being subscribed to by client</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool Subscribe(string type,)
{
    bool IsSubscribed = false;
    try
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Elements":
            {
                logger.Info("Subscribing toPublisher");
                Subscriber.SubscribeToElements(ElementResponse);
                logger.Info("Subscription Completed");
                IsSubscribed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
    }

    return IsSubscribed;
}


public void ElementResponse(Element element, SubscriptionEvent.ActionType eventActionType)
{
    try
    {
        //  stuff to Do
        // Need to Callback to main application
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

*Program.cs*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SubscriberClient client = new SubscriberClient();
    client.Subscribe("SlateQueueElements");

    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
            break;
    }
}
```

So how do I get the Element Response information back to the main project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a callback then you need to specify one as an argument. I've made some assumptions but this should work:

```
public bool Subscribe(string type, Action callback)
{
    bool IsSubscribed = false;
    try
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Elements":
            {
                logger.Info("Subscribing toPublisher");
                Subscriber.SubscribeToElements((e,t) => ElementResponse(e,t,callback));
                logger.Info("Subscription Completed");
                IsSubscribed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }    
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
    }

    return IsSubscribed;
}

public void ElementResponse(Element element, SubscriptionEvent.ActionType eventActionType, Action callback)
{
    try
    {
        //  stuff to Do
        callback();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

I used an [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate, but anything can be put in its place as long as you have a way to call it. The program code will be:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SubscriberClient client = new SubscriberClient();
    client.Subscribe("SlateQueueElements", () => 
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Calling back...");
    });

    while (true)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That works thank you.. turned out the subscription was providing an paramater of type object I was able to pass it through. I ended up using a delegate, but I can see where this will work just the same. Thanks again!